# Rebuild Windows 10 Start Menu

Tags: windows, start-menu

I accidentally deleted my `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` directory; apparently though this is the directory Cortana uses to discover application shortcuts so you can search Cortana for an app.

How can I "discover" all the installed programs on my computer and add/create the start menu shortcuts? Obviously I prefer not to attempt this by hand.

I have Windows 10.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but would it be possible to use something like Piriform Recuva to recover the missing directories and files?

Comment: Add it as an official answer so I can upvote it and mark it for you, it's not..."perfect" but it made the job a lot shorter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible option would be to use Piriform Recuva, and restore the missing files and folders.

https://www.piriform.com/recuva